# Ratchet: Still Connecting State

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, composer-php, ratchet

I'm beginner about this websocket and I'm trying this Ratchet for my first project..

I've done the install tutorial in http://socketo.me by executing this command in command prompt

`composer require cboden/ratchet`

after that, it automatically generates `vendor` folder with a couple of libaries there and on home path a `composer.json` and `composer.lock`

Then I made a `chat.php` file and copied the code from the quick example on ratchet git which is :

```
<?php
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

    // Make sure composer dependencies have been installed
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

/**
 * chat.php
 * Send any incoming messages to all connected clients (except sender)
 */
class MyChat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from != $client) {
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        $conn->close();
    }
}

    // Run the server application through the WebSocket protocol on port 8080
    $app = new Ratchet\App('localhost', 8080);
    $app->route('/chat', new MyChat);
    $app->route('/echo', new Ratchet\Server\EchoServer, array('*'));
    $app->run();
```

Then I execute this command in command prompt: `php chat.php`

I still having error in my client side saying:

**Chrome**
`Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.`

**Firefox**
`InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable`

My folderization (on XAMPP):

Client

`htdocs/public/chat/index.php` with a `common.js` intact that contains

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/echo');
    conn.onmessage = function(e) { console.log(e.data); };
    conn.send('Hello Me!');
```

Server

```
htdocs/public/chatserver/chat.php
htdocs/public/chatserver/vendor/<some libraries>
htdocs/public/chatserver/composer.json
htdocs/public/chatserver/composer.lock
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

please try it like this:

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/echo');
conn.onmessage = function(e) { console.log(e.data); };
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
    conn.send('Hello Me!');
};
```

you should be able to send when the connection is open. It seems to be the case that you try it before the connection is established.

Comment: This solves the error yet the message didn't received by the clients connected.

Comment: Maybe you should connect to `'ws://localhost:8080/chat` if the client should receive something.  You added a route to /chat where the broadcast logic happens. I am not familar with echo server.

Comment: PSA: I'm seeing onopen being called twice in Chrome sometimes. First with readyState === CONNECTING then with readyState === OPEN. It typically happens when the connection is not established immediately because the server was slow to respond.

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem and fixed it with [Troubleshooting](http://socketo.me/docs/troubleshooting) A1:
[You missed a step](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world#next_steps). I missed indeed this part in my server php

```
$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ),
    8080
);
```

Comment: I come to the conclusion that this is the correct answer, comparing the code in the question with the one in the above link "You missed a step".